# where to get full featured IG client for ubuntu

Tags: instagram

Is there any app for ubuntu to use instagram with full features such as direct messaging ?

Answer (score 6):

[Instagraph](https://www.tecrobust.com/how-to-install-instagraph-on-ubuntu/) is an unofficial native Instagram client which is packaged as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install instagraph
```

Features:

- customizable Instagraph feeds
- make photo collections
- multiple edit options
- video live possible

Instagram Direct (icon with the red message notification) is not available in the Instagram desktop web app.

[image: Instagram Direct]

There is another Instagram desktop app (`sudo snap install istekram`) that says that it supports Instagram direct messaging, but istekram is lightweight and not full-featured. It's just a simple HTML wrapper for Instagram built with Electron.

Comment: is Direct messaging available through this app ?

Comment: instagramport is not found

Comment: This soft is now obsolete and broken.

Comment: installed, thanks

Comment: @RYOENGLianHu Have fun using in Instagram. IGTV is a great new Instagram feature.